# Eclipse fails to debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I cannot debug a java aplication inside eclipse.
I'm using:
Windows 7 64bit
Java 6_45 64 bit (tried JDK and JRE)
Eclipse Kepler 64 bit

eclipse always hangs while saying Constructing command line..

I found this (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=195185) that appears to closed for a long time. This is the exact same behavior I'm experiencing, but cannot figure out the cause.
Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly aware of the numbers. But Kepler requires more RAM. What your RAM size? Maybe someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Just to rule these out: did you try rebooting your computer? Reinstalling Eclipse?

Comment: Have a look at .. /workspace/.metadata/.log.

Comment: I tried with several eclipse versions, several workspaces, JDK, JRE. And yes, I rebooted the computer several times... :( gotta check metadata log

Comment: Finally I could go back to this. I found some warning messages related to GIT. So I reacted to those warnings, cleaned the error log console and restarted eclipse. No log what so ever i s present now. After eclipse hangs and I shut it down, eclipse process keeps running on background and I have to kill it manually. This is to weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a few more experiments and reading the bug report again, I changed the Installed JRE from JDK to JRE and now it works. Though it should work with JDK... I can now work, so I'll consider this answered.

Comment: lifesaver. dont know why the JDK didnt work. but changing the build path to use JRE works like a charm.