# Eclipse debugging hangs at 89% (constructing command line)

Tags: java, eclipse, powershell, command-line

My programming instructor went to show us as a class the eclipse debugger today, only to find out that the class was unable to debug because we all had the issue of the progress bar hanging at 89%, with the comment "constructing command line". Earlier in the year, the network security decided to disable command line privileges for the entire school, so we're assuming that's the reason, but I was wondering if there was a way around it. The network security team didn't disable PowerShell, so I tried using the EasyShell plugin to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887997/eclipse-fails-to-debug

Comment: I hadn't seen that before but I'll give it a shot. Thanks!
Edit: No luck, I tried setting the JRE from JDK 1.8 to JRE 1.8 (fresh install) and the same error occurs.